# How do I execute well-timed taunt kills?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I want to know if TF2 taunt kills can be done during the heat of battle.

I have looked it up TF2 wiki but I cannot find anything satisfactory. The closest thing is a YT demo of a Scout stunning a Sniper, pointing to the sky and then kill him with a bat.

Any videos of live game taunt kills would be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: In one video I saw, the spy was camping a teleporter and mass-taunting people coming out of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My best advice is to **predict where the enemy is going to go**. For example, if an enemy was going down the vents in [Turbine](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Turbine), you may want wait behind a bend and initiate your taunt kill, so that it will hit the enemy when he turns the corner.

One particular taunt kill I got, I saw a Soldier coming up the path. I retreated and waited behind where he was going to pop out of, and taunted.

If your goal is specifically to get a taunt kill, you may want to favor certain classes. Heavy has the fastest taunt kill, with Pyro's Hadouken slightly slower than the Heavy's.

Comment: But you missed the spy!

Comment: Ahaha yeah, I only noticed him when I went to edit the replay.

Comment: "Heavy has the fastest taunt kill, with Pyro's Hadouken slightly slower than the Heavy's." <-- Actually, isn't the Sniper's taunt kill the fastest?

Comment: Medic's is pretty fast too, I think.

Comment: @Kevin Y: _"your goal"_  Yes, I was thinking of getting some achievements that way. One viable situation I can think up is where 2 players cornered a lone enemy (Scout or Engineer) and both perform taunt kills. It could backfire though, giving the enemy a double-kill. ;D

Comment: @Powerlord: The stabbing maneuver only stuns as far as I know. He can miss that, but still hit someone else walking by when he pulls the arrow back. That takes a little longer. But if someone does get stunned then it's a guaranteed kill unless the victim or the Sniper himself is removed.

Comment: As for taunt kill speeds, there's really 3 speeds: Slow, Medium, and Fast.  From memory, fast are Heavy, Pyro, and Sniper; medium are Medic and Demoman; slow are Soldier, Engineer (both of them), Spy, and Scout.  Scout is by far the slowest, but it's also the only silent one since a recent update added a voice clip to the Sniper taunt kill.

Comment: I'm just going by what the [TF2 Wiki page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Taunts) says. Supposedly, Pyro and Heavy have 3 second taunts, Soldier, Engineer, Medic, and Sniper have 4 second taunts, and Scout, Demoman, and Spy have 5 second taunts. But yes, the Sniper stuns in the middle of his taunt.

Comment: @KevinY - Video link is dead, if it's your channel can you update it?

Answer (score 8):

If you like to use the scout, and you have the sandman and the bonk energy drink, you can always drink your bonk and then taunt with your sandman to be sure you won't get killed.

Answer (score 3):

Pick your target well.

The worst classes to target are **Scouts, Pyros and Medics**.  These are classes that are constantly moving around and trying to be unpredictable.  You are not likely to get a taunt kill on any of them unless you are really lucky.

**The Spy** is also not a good target.  You won't often know where he is anyway, and if you botch, he can destroy you with a single backstab very quickly.

**Soldiers and Demomen** move more slowly on the ground, so you can try to catch them unaware, but do NOT try to taunt kill them if they are rocket jumping, sticky jumping, or demoknighting.

That leaves you with **Heavies, Engineers and Snipers**, your best taunt kill targets.

Heavies move very slowly, and are easily distracted by their own machine gun.  Unless you have perfect timing it is NOT recommended to ambush them around a corner, as they will likely tear you apart with their machine gun before you can get your taunt off. Flank them from behind when the rest of his team is distracted, then strike.

Engineers tend to feel pretty safe around their nests, which means they stay in one place a lot and go back and forth between specific points on the map repeatedly.   Be careful though of their sentry.

Snipers.

Snipers are the absolute easiest class to taunt kill.

They will focus down their scope for days, completely oblivious to the world around them, feeling perfectly safe wearing their razorbacks.  Even huntsmen snipers tend to focus just before a shot.

So there you have it.  Heavies, Snipers, and unaware engineers are your best targets.  Soldiers and Demomen can sometimes work too, but you'll have a very hard time getting Scouts, Medics or Pyros taunt-killed, and Spies can be too dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

There are two relatively easy ways to do this, that works with most taunt kills.  Ill show some examples of taunt kills I've gotten myself, years ago

**Corner Camp**
Stand on a corner and get lucky ! (relatively lucky, there is some technique to it).
Busy corners, and long animations help the most here.
Example:

**Sneaky!**
Sneak up behind them, preferably a sniper as they tend not to move too much, and give em a good whack.
Example:

Answer (score 2):

Playing as the Heavy with the Holiday Punch gloves equipped, you can hit enemies from behind to make the enemy laugh. While they're laughing you can easily taunt-kill them

Answer (score 1):

Another idea might be to do this. If you're being chased, and you think you can time it right, round a corner, wait if necessary, then perform the taunt. I've seen this done many times before, but that doesn't mean you'll get it. Remember, practice makes perfect!